# Way to solve graphical issue on virtualbox 7 guest

Tags: virtualbox

After update kernel on ubuntu 22.04, we're experiencing a inconvenience on starting virtualbox 6.2, due to classic "please use modprobe vboxsvc". So we decided to upgrade virtualbox to latest and remount the virtual machine. At this point all goes fine, but graphical environment has crashed after/before start guest without see any log.

Commands used on host:

1. `sudo dmesg | grep fail`
   says: `vboxdrv: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel`

¿How can we resolve it?

Answer (score -1):

This work if u need to backup the guest content:

1. If u signed the oldest virtualbox kernel module, disable UEFI on host BIOS.
2. Open virtualbox and start guest into recovery mode/kernel panic (follow steps to corresponding guest OS).
3. make a backup copy of needed files.

In case u're using Windows guest please follow this steps:

1. Open **VirtualBox 7** and **select** the **affected guest**
2. Click on **Configuration** button.
3. Click on **Screen** and find graphical controller droppable menu.
4. Select **VBoxVGA** driver (and uncheck 3d Accel).
5. Save & start machine.

Tip: Do not update/upgrade actual guest addons installed on guest machine.

(Adding some more steps, please come back later)