# Virtualbox error on 22.04: kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)

Tags: 22.04, virtualbox

After last Ubuntu update, when I try to start a VM, I've got this error:

> Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)

> The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver is either not loaded or not set up correctly. Please reinstall virtualbox-dkms package and load the kernel module by executing
> 'modprobe vboxdrv'
> as root.

If I execute `sudo modprobe vboxdrv`, then I get this:

> FATAL: Module vboxdrv not found in directory /lib/modules/6.5.0-14-generic

If I reinstall the package, then I get this:

> Building initial module for 6.5.0-14-generic
> ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/virtualbox-dkms.0.crash'
> Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.5.0-14-generic (x86_64)
> Consult /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.38/build/make.log for more information.
> dpkg: error al procesar el paquete virtualbox-dkms (--configure)

Any ideas, please?

Comment: Did your recent updates include a kernel update?  Check the logs in `/var/log/apt/history.log` to see if a Kernel update was among your last updates.

Comment: I'm not sure. Is this a kernel update?
Start-Date: 2024-01-11  19:36:31
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.458'
Install: linux-modules-extra-6.5.0-14-generic:amd64 (6.5.0-14.14~22.04.1, automatic), linux-hwe-6.5-headers-6.5.0-14:amd64 (6.5.0-14.14~22.04.1, automatic), linux-modules-6.5.0-14-generic:amd64 (6.5.0-14.14~22.04.1, automatic), linux-image-6.5.0-14-generic:amd64 (6.5.0-14.14~22.04.1, automatic), linux-headers-6.5.0-14-generic:amd64 (6.5.0-14.14~22.04.1, automatic)
Upgrade: linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 (6.2.0.39.40~22.04.16, ...

Comment: same issue, i'm working on that [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1499738/way-to-solve-graphical-issue-on-virtualbox-7-guest). Could/Did u tried to disable UEFI & boot?.

Comment: I think you need a newer virtualbox; when I read https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Changelog  this.

Comment: Forgot one link https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Changelog-6.1?ref=news.itsfoss.com

Comment: I'm the same as you. I cannot access my Virtual Machines with the same error message. I tried to remove and reinstall the VirtualBox on Ubuntu, but it has not been solved yet.

Comment: See my [answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1499756/virtualbox-stopped-working-with-kernel-upgrade-ubuntu-22-04). Please comment.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your comments.
Finally solved uninstalling virtualbox 6.x and installing virtualbox 7